# SQL query for updating based on results

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to update records based on a secondary statement but i dont know how to link them together.

```
UPDATE WEBSITE SET CMS_ID = 99
SELECT * 
FROM website
WHERE is_scanned =  'yes'
AND cms_id =0
```

I want to update table website set the colum cms_id to 99 where all websites is_scanned = yes and cms_id = 0

will my query work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query doesn't work ?

```
UPDATE website SET cmd_id = 99
WHERE is_scanned = 'yes' AND cms_id = 0;
```

Comment: Indeed, it worked i must be tired, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

I think this accomplishes the goal you stated and should work in most databases:

```
UPDATE WEBSITE SET CMS_ID = 99
WHERE is_scanned =  'yes'
AND cms_id =0
```

The SELECT FROM is not required unless joins between different records or tables are important to the goal of the update.  [Here are some other examples for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)